# Who owns my question?

Tags: discussion, support

I was searching for an answer to a question on the internet, a simple:

> How do I convert a string to Byte[] in SSIS?

I eventually found [this question: http://whyprogramming.com/sql-server/493682-How-do-I-convert-a-String-to-a-BlobColumn-in-SSIS](http://whyprogramming.com/sql-server/493682-How-do-I-convert-a-String-to-a-BlobColumn-in-SSIS)

Seeing the question it re-jogged my memory and I realised that this was a question I had asked, but I had posted it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703025/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-blobcolumn-in-ssis/35703205#35703205) and have never heard nor posted to the whyprogramming.com site.

So my question is this:

- Is this an infringement of copyright in some way?
- Who actually owns my question? Me? Stack Overflow? Nobody?
- What should be done in this situation?

Comment: You own your content. Stack Overflow owns an irrevocable license to your content (they own a "copy", if you will). Scraper sites infringe on that license to your content if they don't follow the rules outlined by the terms of the license.